# Problems with MySQL replication. Why binlogs grows so fast?

Tags: mysql, docker, replication

I have 2 MySQL servers:
Master server: mysql version 5.7.14
Slave server: mysql version 5.7.14 in Docker container (from official docker hub).
GTID-replication.

I have two problems:

1. Binlogs growth very fast. I set 2 days limit rotation, but this not help - every day binlog folder increases at least twice (first day 25Gb, second 50, third 80 etc).
2. Slave server "seconds behind master" increases.

Servers in local network (100 mbit/s), SSD disks, Database size near 40Gb.
I clone db for slave with Percona Xtrabackup.

Maybe configuration of servers is not correct & I need to fix something?

This is Master my.cnf file:

```
[client]
port            = 3306
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

[mysqld_safe]
pid-file        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
nice            = 0

[mysqld]
user            = mysql
pid-file        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port            = 3306
basedir         = /usr
datadir         = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir          = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
explicit_defaults_for_timestamp

max_allowed_packet = 256M

log-error       = /var/log/mysql/error.log

symbolic-links=0

!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/

innodb_buffer_pool_size=15000M
innodb_buffer_pool_instances=1
sql_mode = ''

slow_query_log = 1
slow_query_log_file     = '/var/log/mysql/slow.log'
long_query_time = 1
log_queries_not_using_indexes = 0

#skip-grant-tables

default_week_format = 1

skip-name-resolve
sort_buffer_size=4M
join_buffer_size=4M
innodb_sort_buffer_size=4M
tmp_table_size=5000M
max_heap_table_size=5000M

[mysqld]
server-id = 1
binlog-format = row
gtid_mode=ON
enforce-gtid-consistency=ON
log-slave-updates
log_bin = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
performance_schema_max_digest_length = 8192
max_digest_length = 8192
max_binlog_size= 1G
expire_logs_days = 2
binlog-ignore-db=check_passport
replicate-ignore-db=check_passport

sync_binlog = 1
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1

key_buffer_size             = 16M
innodb_flush_method         = O_DIRECT
max_connections             = 200

#innodb_temp_data_file_path=ibtmp1:12M:autoextend:max:5G
```

This is my.cnf of slave server

```
[client]
port                        = 3306
socket                      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

[mysqld_safe]
socket                      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
nice                        = 0

[mysqld]
sql_mode                    = ""
character_set_server        = utf8
collation_server            = utf8_general_ci
user                        = mysql
pid-file                    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket                      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port                        = 3306
basedir                     = /usr
datadir                     = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir                      = /tmp
language                    = /usr/share/mysql/english
old_passwords               = 0
bind-address                = 127.0.0.1
skip-host-cache
skip-name-resolve

skip-external-locking

# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0

max_allowed_packet          = 256M
#key_buffer_size             = 16M
innodb_buffer_pool_size     = 2048M
innodb_log_file_size        = 256M
innodb_file_per_table       = 1
innodb_flush_method         = O_DIRECT
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit  = 1

max_connections             = 136

query_cache_size            = 0

slow_query_log              = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
long_query_time             = 1

expire_logs_days            = 2
max_binlog_size             = 1G

[mysqldump]
quick
quote-names
max_allowed_packet          = 16M


[mysqld]
server-id = 2
binlog-format = row
gtid_mode=ON
enforce-gtid-consistency=ON

relay-log = /var/log/mysql/mysql-relay-bin.log

log_bin = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log

skip_slave_start

log_slave_updates = 0
read_only = ON

innodb_file_per_table = ON
#innodb_buffer_pool_size = 3G
innodb_flush_method         = O_DIRECT
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit  = 1

max_binlog_size = 1G

#max_relay_log_size = 1G
#relay_log_space_limit = 20G
relay_log_recovery = ON

expire_logs_days = 2

#slave-parallel-workers = 0

binlog-ignore-db=check_passport
replicate-ignore-db=check_passport

replicate-ignore-table=gfk.application_insurance
replicate-ignore-table=gfk.archive_client_building
replicate-ignore-table=gfk.comments_passwords
replicate-ignore-table=gfk.date_interval
```

Output of *SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G*

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
               Slave_IO_State: Waiting for master to send event
                  Master_Host: 192.168.0.4
                  Master_User: slave_user
                  Master_Port: 3306
                Connect_Retry: 60
              Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.004720
          Read_Master_Log_Pos: 518759418
               Relay_Log_File: mysql-relay-bin.000188
                Relay_Log_Pos: 213202356
        Relay_Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.004703
             Slave_IO_Running: Yes
            Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
              Replicate_Do_DB: 
          Replicate_Ignore_DB: check_passport
           Replicate_Do_Table: 
       Replicate_Ignore_Table: gfk.application_insurance,gfk.date_interval,gfk.archive_client_building,gfk.comments_passwords
      Replicate_Wild_Do_Table: 
  Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table: 
                   Last_Errno: 0
                   Last_Error: 
                 Skip_Counter: 0
          Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 213202143
              Relay_Log_Space: 18773097825
              Until_Condition: None
               Until_Log_File: 
                Until_Log_Pos: 0
           Master_SSL_Allowed: Yes
           Master_SSL_CA_File: /var/lib/master_cert/ca.pem
           Master_SSL_CA_Path: 
              Master_SSL_Cert: /var/lib/master_cert/client-cert.pem
            Master_SSL_Cipher: 
               Master_SSL_Key: /var/lib/master_cert/client-key.pem
        Seconds_Behind_Master: 14488
Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: No
                Last_IO_Errno: 0
                Last_IO_Error: 
               Last_SQL_Errno: 0
               Last_SQL_Error: 
  Replicate_Ignore_Server_Ids: 
             Master_Server_Id: 1
                  Master_UUID: 8ab33cfb-bb00-11e6-84cd-fa163eb352dd
             Master_Info_File: /var/lib/mysql/master.info
                    SQL_Delay: 0
          SQL_Remaining_Delay: NULL
      Slave_SQL_Running_State: System lock
           Master_Retry_Count: 86400
                  Master_Bind: 
      Last_IO_Error_Timestamp: 
     Last_SQL_Error_Timestamp: 
               Master_SSL_Crl: 
           Master_SSL_Crlpath: 
           Retrieved_Gtid_Set: 8ab33cfb-bb00-11e6-84cd-fa163eb352dd:62276836-70424802
            Executed_Gtid_Set: 8ab33cfb-bb00-11e6-84cd-fa163eb352dd:1-67413143
                Auto_Position: 1
         Replicate_Rewrite_DB: 
                 Channel_Name: 
           Master_TLS_Version:
```

Comment: how many database you set to replicaton ? from one instance ? because I only see variable `binlog_ignore_db=check_passport`. I assume you doing replicaton all database from one instance mariadb except check_passport

Comment: @febry, we replicate 13 databases from 1 instance except `check_passport` db.

Comment: remember binary log will be created base on activity from database like insert, update, delete i think this is normal because you have 13 database on one instance

Comment: @febry Ok, let's log folder increase more. But how to solve problem with `"seconds behind master"` increasing. Maybe some params in config not correct?

Comment: Let's see the big `DELETEs` and big `UPDATEs` you are running.  There are much better ways to do them.

Comment: Which binlog is growing fast?  On the Primary?  On the Replica?  On both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I found solution for my case**

First of all, I search what databases and tables generates so big binlogs (what tables don't have primary or unique keys):

```
SELECT t.table_schema,t.table_name,engine
FROM information_schema.tables t
INNER JOIN information_schema .columns c
on t.table_schema=c.table_schema
and t.table_name=c.table_name
and t.table_schema not in ('performance_schema','information_schema','mysql')
GROUP BY t.table_schema,t.table_name
HAVING sum(if(column_key in ('PRI','UNI'), 1,0)) =0;
```

Then:

1. My network speed already been 1Gbit/s, there is all ok.
2. I exclude from replication and logging database which recreated every day.
3. I increase on slave RAM to 23Gb (as on master)
4. I move binlogs on slave from SSD to HDD - it's ok - speed of HDD is enough.
5. I set log_slave_updates = 1, because my replication scheme is master>slave>slave.

And this steps solve my problems! For now my binlogs not increase more than 10Gb.

Answer (score 3):

Is it practical for the Primary to have `binlog_ignore = check_passport`?  If so, and if there is a lot of traffic about that db, then that would  shrink the binlogs "a lot".

Big `DELETEs` or `UPDATEs` take a lot of binlog space, hence making the binlog huge.  (Example:  updating every row of a million-row table.)  Provide specifics; the may be significant work-arounds.

How many replica threads are running on the Replica?  This impacts `Seconds_behind_master`.  (More threads, up to some limit, is likely to decrease "behind".)

`innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit  = 1` --> change to 2.  This sacrifices some robustness (across a crash), but improves throughput.

How much RAM in each?  I see a bigger buffer_pool in the Primary.  *Usually* the Replica should be the beefier machine.

100Mbs seems low; can you check to see whether it is saturated.

**Fresh data daily**

Here is an efficient way to replace *all* the data in a table:

1. `CREATE TABLE new LIKE real;`
2. `LOAD DATA INFILE INTO new ...`  -- or whatever it takes
3. `RENAME TABLE real TO old, new TO REAL;
4. `DROP TABLE old;`

Step #2 is the slowest part.
Step #3 is very fast; it is the only time that your table is not available.
No binlog-intensive `UPDATE` or `DELETE`.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer. Yes, this is practical to ignore `check_passport` because this db recreated every day with data from external service.

How to see how many replica threads i am runing (I think default value)?

On the primary 23Gb RAM, on the slave 10Gb RAM.

Comment: @Pavel - I added to my Answer, possibly explaining the binlog bloat.

Comment: Thanks for your addition. I check local network speed - it's 1Gbit/s. And after set `log_slave_updates = 0` my slave catching up master.